# Can you get graphics hardware information from a Windows service using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, service, directx

I am trying to create a service which is going to be used for monitoring client machines and providing updates but part of the service is reporting the hardware that is being used. I currently have the following code to get the GPU information which works when run as a command line application but when it is running as a service no information is returned.

I believe this is due to services not having access to the display but I cannot find any other ways to get the GPU information that would work from a service.

```
QByteArrayList GetGpuNames ()
{
    QByteArrayList list;

    IDirect3D9* d3dobject = Direct3DCreate9 ( D3D_SDK_VERSION );

    if ( !d3dobject )
        return list;

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpresent;
    memset ( &d3dpresent , 0 , sizeof ( D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS ) );
    d3dpresent.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpresent.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    UINT adaptercount = d3dobject->GetAdapterCount ();
    D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9* adapters = ( D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9* ) malloc ( sizeof ( D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9 ) * adaptercount );

    for ( int i = 0; i < adaptercount; i++ )
    {
        d3dobject->GetAdapterIdentifier ( i , 0 , &( adapters [ i ] ) );
        list << QByteArray ( adapters [ i ].Description );
    }

    return list;
}
```